# Can I use Data Management Studio 2012 for 2008 R2 reporting services?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, bids, sql-server-2012

I have a bunch of reports I need to work on for 2008 R2 reporting services.  Can I use the 2012 reporting designer on reports designed for 2008 R2?  Does the 2012 designer know I am working on a 2008 R2 box?

Thanks as always, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Report Builder in SQL Server 2012 will work against a SQL Server 2008 R2 Report Server.